# Inherit NuGet package from another project in the solution

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am trying to have a centralised single project in my solution which references NUnit *(called NUnitHelper)*. Within this project I will add my own wrappers to some NUnit classes and Attributes.

What I want to do is for the other projects in my solution I would like to inherit NUnit from the NUnitHelper project rather than having direct references to the NUnit NuGet package all over my solution.

I am using VS2019. I have found that there used to be a way to do this in the past in that Package Manager had a 'manage' button for each NuGet package that allowed distribution, but this option is not visible for me. TIA.

Comment: Is your issue solved now? Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add a `PackageReference` from your projects to `NUnitHelper`.

Transitive dependencies (i.e. `NUnit`) are available to consuming projects by default.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found that there used to be a way to do this in the past in that Package Manager had a `manage` button for each NuGet package that allowed distribution.

Do you have a screenshot saved about this feature? I checked the Package Manager and also didn’t find this feature.

First of all, assume you are using non-sdk projects, though looks like you installed the same NuGet package for all the projects one by one, even if you install the same NuGet packages for all the projects, the NuGet package will not install twice, three times… it will only install once, as NuGet package manager will help to create a folder in your solution folder, called `packages` and any NuGet packages which you want to install will be downloaded into it. So, the same NuGet Package will not download and install again, it will only do some necessary configurations, unless you download the **different versions** of the same NuGet package.

There is a manager to control this => Solution NuGet Package Manager(Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution…).

[image]

If you are using new-sdk project, this should not be an issue, as, if you installed one NuGet package in one project, then in another project, you just need to add references/dependences to that project and you can use the NuGet package that that project installed.